# Cisco VPN client settings overwritten by one host

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect, profile

I frequently connect to my work vpn, and to the vpn of one of my customers.  Every time I connect to my customer's VPN all the settings from my work VPN are cleared out.  That is, the next time I want to connect to my work VPN I need to enter the entire server name again, but 5 or 6 different available connections from my customer are always listed.

I assume this is because the customer ASA is overwriting any previous connection profile I have.  I can't find the xml files for the profiles ("AppData\Local\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" does not have a sub-folder "profiles".  it only contains one file: "preferences.xml") so maybe I am on the wrong track.  But does this sound likely?

I thought I could resolve this by finding the profiles, editing them, and making them "read-only", but I can't find them.  How is my customer scrubbing my previous connection data?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/639269/cisco-anyconnect-profile-keeps-getting-overwritten/

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the last used profile gets copied into preferences.xml in your default profile location = C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (for Windows 7).

However, all used profiles should be copied into the location C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile (for Windows 7). If they are there, you should see them as selectable on a drop-down list in your AnyConnect client.

You could run into a problem if the folks running the ASAs use the same profile name. In that case, your could build some profiles yourself with the destination ASAs and give them unique names. A basic profile is only a structured handful of lines of plain text saved as an XML file.

Hope it could help.