# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Profile is overwritten after each successful connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I use Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client version 3.1.10010 in Windows 7 in order to connect to three different VPN servers.

AnyConnect Client should keep their hostnames together with their usernames in Profile settings. I found these settings here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\AnyConnectProfile.xml
```

So I put my URLs into the settings file like this:

```
<ServerList>
  <HostEntry>
    <HostName>vpn.aaa.com</HostName>
  </HostEntry>
  <HostEntry>
    <HostName>vpn.bbb.com</HostName>
  </HostEntry>
  <HostEntry>
    <HostName>vpn.ccc.com</HostName>
  </HostEntry>
</ServerList>
```

I started AnyConnect Client and all three hostnames were displayed in the combobox. I connected to one of them (`vpn.aaa.com`) and disconnected a few minutes later.

After that there was just one hostname in the combobox again (the one I connected to) and the XML file was overwritten.

What should I do to save my connection settings persistently? Why is AnyConnect Client overwriting my settings?

---

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/639269/cisco-anyconnect-profile-keeps-getting-overwritten) seems to be very similar, but it provides no solution to my problem, unfortunately. Its answer says:

> The settings within this .xml are not designed to be locally editable
>   and will be overwritten, with the profile that is configured on the
>   ASA, upon successfully connecting.

This is just a fact, not a solution. What should I do to keep all my hostnames with their usernames as options in the combobox?

Comment: It actually does answer your question. Read para 2 line 3 of answer. **The settings within this .xml are not designed to be locally editable and will be overwritten, with the profile that is configured on the ASA, upon successfully connecting.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cisco AnyConnect Profile Keeps Getting Overwritten](http://superuser.com/questions/639269/cisco-anyconnect-profile-keeps-getting-overwritten)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Well, it might answer it... but I don't understand it. What should I do to keep all my hostnames in the combobox? Please, write it as an answer...